# PHP change file extension in HTML as plaintext

Tags: php, regex

I want to change file extension in HTML code on PHP output. Probably with regex and this is something I really cannot handle..

`...some code...<img data-src='https://static.example.com/gallery/image.jpg'>...some code...`

should be changed to

`...some code...<img data-src='https://static.example.com/gallery/image.webp'>...some code...`

Please note that:

- there might be any number of occurances (zero, one, multiple),
- I want to change only those from https://static.example.com/gallery/ and not from  https://example.com nor https://static.example.com
- I dont want to parse it as DOM, because it is so slow for my purpose.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something simple like:

```
(?<='https:\/\/static\.example\.com\/gallery\/)(.*?)(\..*?)(?=')
```

[As seen here at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/2Z1mgH/1).

## Explanation:

We use the regex positive lookbehind in this `(?<=)` which ensures that the match must be preceded by the site name. If you want the site name to be variable too, that's a whole 'nother issue.

As long as the site name is fixed to `static.example.com/gallery/`, we can just capture the name of the file in the first parentheses (capturing group 1), and the dot+extension in capturing group 2. Then we can just replace this match with the file name (1st capturing group `$1`) and the new dot+extension `.webp`.